# How to convert a date which is given in CCYYMMDD format to MM/DD/CCYY using C#?

Tags: c#, date, format

Can anyone help me to convert a date which is given in CCYYMMDD format to MM/DD/CCYY format in C#.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming by "CC" you mean century, you should just parse it and reformat it:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("yyyyMMdd", text,
                                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string newText = date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```