# Need to convert date format in different way in c#?

Tags: c#, date, string-formatting

I need to convert following date format in C#

```
 Actual   : 5/20/2010 3:01:18 PM ==> (IST)
 Required : 20 May 2010 09:31:18 AM ==> (GMT)
```

Is there any built in function in C#?

Comment: Time=5/20/2010 3:01:18 PM;
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(Time, "dd MMM yyyy", null);

Comment: What you posted as the datetime string doesn't match the format string in `ParseExact` at all.

Comment: Instead of analysing the question have research effort or not... please try to give some usefull explaination....just now i am learning to post in stack overflow and learning c# ...u can identify seeing my reputation point :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261143/how-to-convert-a-date-which-is-given-in-ccyymmdd-format-to-mm-dd-ccyy-using-c) (although slightly differently).
This should work.

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("d/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string newText = date.ToString("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Also, see the the [documentation about date format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).