# Convert date format to CCYYMMDD HH:MM:SS

Tags: r

How one goes about to reformat date to `CCYYMMDD HH:MM:SS TZ` ? (the TZ is optional)

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261143/how-to-convert-a-date-which-is-given-in-ccyymmdd-format-to-mm-dd-ccyy-using-c) is related post but I would need the solution within R.

Here are my dates, which I would need to reformat.

```
library(lubridate)

startdate <- as.Date("2015-01-01")

week.dates <- seq(startdate, by="1 week", length.out=12)
dat.week <- week.dates[wday(week.dates) != 1 & wday(week.dates) != 7]
biz.week <- format(as.POSIXct(as.Date(dat.week)), tz="America/Los_Angeles",usetz=TRUE)
```

EDIT: Specifically, needed format is: `'YYYYMMDD{SPACE}hh:mm:ss[{SPACE}TMZ]'`

Comment: What does `CC` mean? What is your desired output?

Comment: @David Arenburg: CC means "century", I suppose.

Comment: It seems CC means "centry" but I don't know exactly, I encountered this first time.

Comment: If the format is the last you provided, try `strftime(dat.week,format="%Y%m%d %H:%M %Z")`.

Comment: @nicola Yes, there is `"20150618"` is `CCYYMMDD`.

Comment: @nicola, post as answer?

Comment: The CC indicates that the centuries are not omitted, which is the difference between `%Y` and `%y`. 
There is a format `%C` for the centuries in a date, so @nicola's solution could equivalently be written as `strftime(dat.week,format="%C%y%m%d %H:%M %Z")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try:

```
strftime(dat.week,format="%Y%m%d %H:%M %Z")
```

You can also use `format` or `as.character` instead of `strftime`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you also requested the seconds, so here's a minor modification:

```
strftime(dat.week,format="%C%y%m%d %H:%M:%S %Z")
```